# GitHub SSH access not working

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I have created a new user on github under our organization which will be used for auto deployment. I followed the article on https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux.

Somehow, when I tried to clone the repository to the server, it worked once. The code was running properly, and I exit the server. Today, we released an update to the code, and I wanted to deploy the code manually to the server, so I ssh'd into the server and tried to pull the repository with `git pull`. It gave me **Permission denied** error. After some debugging I realized that the ssh-agent wasn't running. So I executed the following commands:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa_staging
```

Now, when I try `ssh -T git@github.com`, I see the welcome message which is:

```
Hi *****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But when I try to pull from the repository, I am continuously getting this error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked the repository and the user has *read* access to it. I double checked if the keys match on github and server, yes they do. I tried generating new keys. I tried using ssh/config file. Nothing helped...

I appreciate any help & suggestions!

---

**Update:**

So I figured out that `git clone` command is working properly, but even when I try `git pull` right after git clone, it is giving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `sudo` to `git pull/push` to the remote you need to ensure you used `sudo` to generate your SSH keys. Otherwise you will not be using the same keys that you originally generated.

[github doc for reference](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
For me what worked was

1. Go to repo on github which you have cloned and wanna pull with
2. Under the code-download option copy SSH link
3. Enter following command in your terminal -->
   git remote set-url origin paste_SSH_link